# Incrementar parámetros en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Resulta que tengo esta función de suma:

```js
function sum(a, b) { 
  a = parseFloat(prompt("numero")); 
  b = parseFloat(prompt("numero")); 
  c = a + b; 
  return alert(c);
}
sum(1, 2);
```

se le llame la función el usuario pueda elegir que cantidad de números (parámetros) sumar y colocarlos todos y sumarlos, alguien tiene alguna idea?

A mi me comentaron sobre el objeto arguments pero no entendí muy bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que quieres de la siguiente forma sin necesidad de argumentos:

```js
function sum(n) { 
  var c = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    c += parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
  }

  alert(c);

}

sum(5);
```

También puedes usar [Párametros Rest (documentación)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest), [Párametros Rest (pregunta relacionada)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest) de la siguiente forma:

```js
function sum(...n) { 
  var c = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
    c += n[i];
  }
  
  return c;
  
}

console.log(sum(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)); // 14
console.log(sum(5, 6)); // 11
```

También puedes usar el objeto [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments):

```js
function sum() { 
  var c = 0;
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    c += args[i];
  }
  
  return c;
}

console.log(sum(5, 5)); // 10
console.log(sum(1, 1, 1, 1)); // 4
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya lo he probado y ha funcionado.

Comment: Y si lo que quiero es usar otras operaciones? Como división, resta, multiplicación?

Comment: Me gusta mucho esta respuesta ^^