# Hacer que el parámetro recoja la cantidad de números que se van a multiplicar

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código en `JavaScript`:

```
function mul(a,b){
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var c = a * b;
    return c;
}
```

Ahí yo le paso dos parámetros que de van a multiplicar, pero yo quiero que el usuario sea el que elija la cantidad de parámetros que quiere multiplicar.

También lo quiero hacer con división y resta.

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías corregir tu pregunta para que tanto el título como el contenido estén bien escritos?

Comment: Claro que sí, dame un segundo.

Comment: Esta respuesta te ayudará https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/66975/12864

Answer (score 1):

Esto te podría funcionar

```
function sum() {//declaras tu funcion
  var suma = 0; //declaras una variable local
  //arguments contiene todo los argumentos, la propiedad length regresa
  //la cantidad de elementos que hay de parametros
  for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { 
    suma += arguments[i]; // se suma el total + el valor del argumento
  }
  return(suma); // regresa el total de la suma
}
```

y cuando la mandes a llamar le puedes pasar n numero de parametros `suma(2,3,4,5,7);` etc;

Para poner el código en formato de código aquí en stack, en el ícono de "{}" o seleccionando el texto y presionando ctrl + k.

Formato ES6 usando [parámetros rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest)

```
function sum(...nums) {//declaras tu funcion
  var suma = 0; //declaras una variable local
  //arguments contiene todo los argumentos, la propiedad length regresa
  //la cantidad de elementos que hay de parametros
  for(i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
    suma += nums[i]; // se suma el total + el valor del argumento
  }
  return(suma); // regresa el total de la suma
}
```

Con este tipo de parámetros puedes usar funciones de tipo array como: sort, pop, reverse, etc. que no está disponibles con arguments.

Comment: Y para la resta que haría?

Comment: Lo mismo, solo que en lugar de sumar los argumentos los restas, lo mismo aplica con division o multiplicación, explico el código para que lo entiendas  si te queda duda me dices

Comment: Cambiar `+=` por `-=` para resta, `*=` multiplicación y `/=` división

Comment: Ósea que tengo que cambiar de incremento a decremento en el bucle for?

Comment: Oh ya, gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo a lo simple con [window prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) o puedes hacer un formulario y que en el submit de dicho formulario obtengas los datos y hagas la multiplicación, división o lo que sea.

En el enlace de prompt que te puse tienes un ejemplo con el que probar ;).

Comment: En realidad lo que quiero hacer es con la llamada a la función. Por ejemplo, que cuando yo pongo mul(5); esa función me haga multiplicar 5 números (que voy a colocar en un prompt).

Comment: De igual manera muchas gracias por la respuesta.